# Show Lightbox on form submit

Tags: jquery

I want to sbmit show a page in a lightbox like in this link:

http://www.smkhutankampong.co.cc/infopendidikan.php

I have seen this post : [Lightbox on form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199258/lightbox-on-form-submit)
but I have not understand how I can use the example in the right way.

Please help !

Comment: Waht do you mean with markup ?

Comment: @Bizboss: HTML (HyperText Markup Language). We don't know what your page looks like. We also don't know what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the used facebox:

You may open onsubmit a facebox with an on-the-fly-created iframe, which may be the target of the form.

Provide the markup of the iframe as argument to `jQuery.facebox()` and set the form's target-attribute and the iframes name-attribute to the same value.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/RD88Z/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but I want also to add a close link (X), and to center in in the screen, exactly like the given link : http://www.smkhutankampong.co.cc/infopendidikan.php

Thanks for more help :)

Comment: @Bizboss: If you just want to rip-off an existing implementation, why not email the webmaster of that site and ask him/her for permission to copy the code?

Answer (score 0):

in the given link they are using Jquery facebook plugin to show the lightbox.
You can do in a similar way, ie in the form submission after successful form submission show the lightbox

`jQuery.facebox({ div: '#div1' });`  div1 contains the contents to be shown in popup.

You can find javascript code they have done by taking the page source.